# How to calculate the world position of the corner of the viewport?

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d

I have a 3d plane at the world origin. How do I translate it so that it appears on the upper right corner of the canvas?

Comment: What are you using to render 3D graphics? What is the code you've tried? How did you make your 3D plane? Please make a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I am using C++. So far I have tried getting the viewport coordinates and projecting viewport to world coordinates to get the origin of the plane in 3d world

Comment: how is this different from your last 2 questions? If you have new iinfo you can add it to your current post instead of creating new one ... Also you still did not share MCVE (with actual values you use) so we can only guess ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to undo camera transformation and perspective?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67078963/how-to-undo-camera-transformation-and-perspective)